# How to manage cache for large e-commerce website

Tags: php, caching, redis

This is my first time creating cache system for large website and im not sure how to do it.

My question is: should i use Redis cache of File cache system ?

Information about project

1. Base on PHP MVC framework
2. Database: 100k products, 400k images, 10k filters, 800 categories

Comment: You don't want 50K files in one directory, just use Redis for everything, and then you can easily control when things automatically expire.

Comment: @AlexHowansky around how much products will able to cache Redis with set of 512 RAM ?

Comment: Absolutely no idea, but it doesn't matter. If you have a self-described "large e-commerce site" then your hosting company shouldn't be dictating anything to you. This isn't the sort of project you run on a $5 a month shared plan with cpanel. You should have an infrastructure with dedicated VMs and/or containers that you have full control over.

Comment: ^ This. There is no technical workaround for simply not having the budget to cover your resource requirements.

Comment: If you really _are_ building a "large" site of this type (although your definition of "large" may be different to ours, of course), consider hiring a cloud architect to design you something properly scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the cache persistence mechanism, this is called a "pull-through" cache strategy.

To your actual questions:

1. Even in modern filesystems directory lookup performance usually starts to noticeably degrade around the 10k entry mark, and 50k is well past that. As-written, your code would do one lookup for every request, and a second for every cache hit.
2. Probably, but that's not going to be simple or fun to implement. The alternative would be simply deleting the cache entirely from time to time, and that's going to be its own problem due to having 50k directory entries and `rm -f cache/*` or similar will break down due to shell expansion limitations.
3. Yes. Just use Redis. Redis will handle cache TTLs and "last-used" eviction to keep you under a set memory limit. Unless you have *very* stringent requirements there's generally no good reason to cache every single scrap of data. The cache will naturally settle on the set of data that is most frequently requested being resident in the cache.

In general, you should also have resource monitoring enabled for your server so that you can track your CPU/memory/IO/etc over time and make informed decisions on how to architect your app/stack.

Opinion: Disk IO is generally your most limited resource, so you should only cache things there that are:

1. Large enough to push out an unacceptable amount of data from the memory cache.
2. Resource-intensive enough to justify pulling from disk rather than re-computing/re-fetching/etc.